# Preload the datas in local database in Window phone 8 development

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows pnone 8 application development.  In my application I need to use local database where datas are constant.(should stored already in database).  I gothrough the the following link to use the local database. The datas are giving in runtime.  However, How can I preload the datas into the database?
.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: You should define 'constant date' as default constraint, in 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' format in your sqlite file when you define your table schema.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same code which initializes/created database to fill it with required data.

From the tutorial you linked to:

```
using (ToDoDataContext db = new ToDoDataContext(ToDoDataContext.DBConnectionString))
{
    if (db.DatabaseExists() == false)
    {
        //Create the database
        db.CreateDatabase();

        //Fill database with data you need
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Also, In the code all the dbdesign are done using code. Is there a easy way/tool to design the schema of Database?

Comment: That's called *Code First* and I don't think you can skip it in SQL Lite and WP8. That's how you describe your database.

Comment: Thanks, Finally..How the splash screen gets loaded initially, I couldn't find any reference denoting navigate to splashscreen image in codewise

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on what DB you are using, but when you go for SQL CE you can pre load an existing db at start up of your app.
Take a look at this article for all the details: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286411(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286411%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

But what you need is the class: `DataHelper` with the method `MoveReferenceDatabase` - the code is in the article.
Your SQL CE db can be modified using SQL Management studio, or you could use the tools of Erik show here: http://erikej.blogspot.be/2013/04/generate-windows-phone-8-local-database.html